# Не подключаются CSS-стили

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

По идее на странице все должно быть красным, но стили не подключаются никак.
https://wampi.ru/image/RcqGppq

> [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<title>MoGo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>MoGo</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Это CSS:

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: это как? обьясните пожалуйста

Comment: https://wampi.ru/image/RcqMxNJ В папке MoGo файл с HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все просто: Я просто удалил проект и заново создал все папки и файлы. Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю что у вас за структура проекта, я составил рабочий пример на основе тех данных, что дали вы.

Я создал папку: `MoGo`

Разместил в ней файл `index.html` и создал папку `assets`, внутрь папки `assets` я поместил папку `css` и внутрь папки `css` я поместил файл `style.css`

В файле `index.html` я подключил в head стили с помощью относительного пути (относительно пути файла `index.html`) : `assets/css/style.css`

---

### Код `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MoGo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MoGo Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### Код `assets/css/style.css`:

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

---

*Все было протестировано без какого-либо локального сервера, OC **Windows 10**.*

Comment: У меня теперь точно так же, но по прежнему не работает ОС Windows 8.1. В других проектах все норм

Comment: @John в таком случае могу предложить только установку локального сервера для проекта. `Xampp` или `OpenServer`. С ним я думаю у вас проблем не возникнет. Я лично тестировал и все отрабатывает как положено, что творится у вас я к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: XAMPP у меня установлен на другом проекте с базой данных, как его подключить к мого?